# Primefaces p:tree commandButton action not working

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

When I click buttons near node0, node1, node2, it is printing "TEST on the console. However, when I click on others, it is not working. What can be the problem?

```xml
<h:form id="form">  
    <p:tree value="#{treeBean.root}" var="node" id="tree" dynamic="true">  
        <p:treeNode id="treeNode">
            <p:commandButton value="test" action="#{treeBean.test()}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{node}" id="lblNode"/>  
        </p:treeNode>  
    </p:tree>  
</h:form>
```

```java
public class TreeBean {  

    private TreeNode root;  

    public TreeBean() {  
        root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);  
        TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0", root);  
        TreeNode node1 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1", root);  
        TreeNode node2 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 2", root);  

        TreeNode node00 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0", node0);  
        TreeNode node01 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1", node0);  

        TreeNode node10 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0", node1);  
        TreeNode node11 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.1", node1);  

        TreeNode node000 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.0", node00);  
        TreeNode node001 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.1", node00);  
        TreeNode node010 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1.0", node01);  

        TreeNode node100 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0.0", node10);  
    }  

    public TreeNode getRoot() {  
        return root;  
    }  

    public void test(){
        System.out.println("TEST");
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "click on others" , can it be that your other buttons are outside your `h:form`

Comment: I mean buttons near Node 0.0, etc. it is inside h:form. It is part of tree.

Comment: Tested with Primefaces 3.5 + Mojarra 2.1.25 in Tomcat 6, works perfectly for me.

Comment: I am working with primefaces 3.5 + GlassFish Server 3.1.2.2, not working fine.

Comment: @XtremeBiker thank you. I have upgraded my Mojarra to 2.1.25 and the problem is solved.